# Android Setting image from string

Tags: android, string, image, android-imageview

I have this code where I want to set an image from a string:

```
String imagename = "mypicture";
ImageView lblPic = new ImageView(this);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());
lblPic.setImageResource(resID);
```

This is my xml file.

```
<ImageView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/image1" android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
```

Where could there be a problem? I think I've setup xml file wrong...? I've tried many codes but every time Java code doesn't change the picture, it stays as it was in xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct :

```
  <ImageView  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/image1" 
          android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
```

Place this line in onCreate Method of your Activity :

```
ImageView lblPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());
lblPic.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: Thanks. And i found out that i have to use filename without extension :)